# Multiple dbContexts in ASP.NET vNext and EF7

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to get along with building web systems with ASP.NET vNext using MVC 6 and EF7. I'm looking at this tutorial: http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2015/01/17/asp-net-5-and-angularjs-part-4-using-entity-framework-7

On the page you'll see how to add a dbContext to a project and it's registered in the startup file like this:

```
// Register Entity Framework
services.AddEntityFramework(Configuration)
        .AddSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<MoviesAppContext>();
```

And the context class looks like this:

```
public class MoviesAppContext:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
}
```

It all works good, but now I'm in need of adding an additional DbContext. Though I don't know how to register this additional context so that it will be used by EF and possible to use in my project.

Let's say I've created a new context like this:

```
public class MyNewSuper:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Model1> Model1 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Model2> Model2 { get; set; }
}
```

How do I go ahead to register it for use in my project then?

Comment: Did you try appending to the list of `DbContexts`? `services.AddEntityFramework(Configuration)
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<MoviesAppContext>()
            .AddDbContext<MyNewSuper>();`

Comment: Can you not do all this with one context and three entities within that context?

Comment: If your `DBSet`s are in the same database, use the same `DbContext`. If they are in different databases, you will need to do much more if you want to get correct transactional behavior.

Comment: Alright. Well I was initially planning going with two databases. But I'll maybe leave that until later. Though I'm having some other issues right now preventing me from adding migration with the "k ef migration add" command. So I'll have to look into that first.

Comment: @Alex - can you give a link or explain what you meant about "do much more to get transactional behavior" out of different databases - I've have tried really hard at this and found it impossible to get that behavior out of seperate databases

Comment: @ScottSelby I mean you have to coordinate every transaction you do, That is doable if the information from the two databases is not connected in any way and not used in the same transaction scope (i.e. they belong to different bounded contexts). As soon at they are required to work within the same transaction scope things become complicated, and you will need e.g. a transaction coordinator such as MSDTC. That is complex, slow and has corner cases that still allow messing things up.

Comment: so basically - there is nothing I'm missing , just use ContextA to get the data you need then use that to call contextB is probably the best ?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29870490/multiple-dbcontexts-in-asp-net-vnext-and-ef7/30849619#30849619) question

Answer (score 14):

**Important Note:** The syntax for configuring the Entity Framework 7 services has changed since this post, which was accurate as of the last few beta rounds. The same idea should still apply to the new syntax though.

Here is what I've been doing:

```
services.AddEntityFramework().AddSqlServer()
                .AddDbContext<DataContextA>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.Get("StorageSettings:SQLConnectionString")))
                .AddDbContext<DataContextB>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.Get("StorageSettings:SQLConnectionString")));
```

where `StorageSettings:SQLConnectionString` is a connection string for a SQL Express database. Currently, I have both DataContextA and DataContextB sharing the same database, but you can keep them separate. If you want to keep using the `Configuration` method (which I wasn't aware of, pretty cool!) you could do something like this:

```
{
    "Data": {
        "DefaultConnectionA": { 
            "ConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=ContextADatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
        "DefaultConnectionB": { 
            "ConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=ContextBDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
        }
    },
    "EntityFramework": {
        "DataContextA": {
            "ConnectionStringKey": "Data:DefaultConnectionA:ConnectionString"
        }            
        "DataContextB": {
            "ConnectionStringKey": "Data:DefaultConnectionB:ConnectionString"
        }
    }
}
```

with

```
services.AddEntityFramework(Configuration)
                .AddSqlServer()
                .AddDbContext<DataContextA>()
                .AddDbContext<DataContextB>();
```

Both `DataContextA` and `DataContextB` can be injected into your controller:

```
public class MyController: Controller {
    public MyController(DataContextA dataA, DataContextB dataB) {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the example, I will probablt try it out later.

Comment: How does this work with Migrations?  How are the migrations separated in the migrations table when using the same database but multiple db contexts? @cuddlebunny

Comment: @dotnethaggis I haven't tried anything like this. If you have two databases, I you should get two separate migration tables: one per database. If you have only one but two DbContexts, I would hope that it has only one migration table that is shared. I'm not certain though, try it out and see what happens!

Comment: @CuddleBunny yes you get one migration table.  History is now managed in code.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in something like config.json you can add yur connection strings.  Something like the following will work

```
  "Data": {
    "BlogData": { "ConnectionString": "Server=tcp:YourHostname.net,1433;Database=YourDatabaseName;User ID=YourDBUser@YourDomain;Password=YourPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;" },
    "Identity": { "ConnectionString": "Server=tcp:YourHostname.net,1433;Database=YourDatabaseName;User ID=YourDBUser@YourDomain;Password=YourPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;" }
  },
```

You then have two DBContexts. Let's say: 
YourApp.AppDBContext and YourApp.AppIdentityDBContext

You need to include these at the top of your CS file of course.

```
using YourApp.AppDBContext;
using YourApp.AppIdentityDBContext;
```

In startup.cs for example, in the startup method, your configuration builder will look like this:

```
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("config.json")
        .AddJsonFile($"config.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
    builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

In the ConfigureServices method you will add your DBContexts as follows:

```
    services.AddEntityFramework()
        .AddSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:BlogData:ConnectionString"]))
        .AddDbContext<AppIdentityDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:Identity:ConnectionString"]));
```

I hope this helps. Feel free to give me a shout if I can expand on this further.